# Strength and magnetic charge of KNO3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

A question asks for physical properties of potassium nitrate, and specifically asks for "magnetic charge" and "strength" (that is how it is phrased). I have properties such as white in color, vitreous, odorless, and melting point of $\pu{334^\circ C}$. It is relatively stable, and a strong oxidizer, so it acts as a good fuel source. However, is strength asking about bond strength? And I'm not sure how to find the magnetic charge since none of my research has found anything.

Comment: Surely there is some mistake, as nothing in the Universe that we know of has been measured to [possess a magnetic charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole).

Comment: That's why I specifically stated that they phrased it that way. If anyone has an idea about what they could be referring to I would appreciate any help. Or help with the strength portion? It's ionic, so it's strength is greater than covalent, but is it really that simple?